# How can I create a folder and a file before spring boot application load the application.propeties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jks

We have a spring boot application that uses an application.properties file that contains  two values that are similar to:

```
file.file=folder/name.jks
file.file2=folder2/name2.jks
```

these files are required when the application starts.

now, we need to read two environment variables to build these files, but the problem here is that we need to do it before the application loads the application.properties file

I tried to do something like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method.toCreateFiles();
        SpringApplication.run(app.class);
}
```

and the environment variables are empty (I suppose that the reason is about the server configuration, and we can not change this easily).

So, we need to read the environment variables into the spring boot context, but first that the application.properties file is loaded because the path of files is needed at this point, I'd like to know some ideas to do that.

Comment: Look for `CommandLineRunner`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Are those environment or system variables as those are different. You can just read them without Spring using `System.getenv` if it is a system property use `System.getProperty`. I suspect you are using the wrong one.

Comment: From my understand, values that I need to use are environment variables (idk why are empty but...), and currently I'm using "System.getenv", do u think that it could be the problem?

Comment: sorry ..i meant command line arguents not commandlinerunner ; @M.Deinum: Isn't `System.getenv` for the 'other/inner side' to get the args from the spring context into application code? But -as i understood- he is looking for a way to inject args into context before `application.properties` is loaded..

Comment: Well people confusingly use environment and system properties interchangibly. Try `System.getProperty` instead of `System.getenv`.

Comment: @user3192295 `System.getenv` has nothing to do with Spring it will get the actual environment variables from your OS. It doesn't even know about Spring as it is plain java.